# Как отдать JSON после writeHead

Tags: node.js, json, express

Есть приложение на экспрессе. Я пробую сделать так:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
...
res.send(JSON.stringify({'result': '1', 'path': outputFile}));
```

На фронте:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
```

res.json использовать не могу, нужно именно после writeHead.
Но в итоге на клиенте получаю не JSON, а обычную строку. Как это можно исправить именно со стороны сервера?

Comment: res.json(data) без заголовков и т.п. и покажите как data выглядит на сервере до отправки

Comment: добавил........

Comment: res.json не сработает после writeHead

Comment: вместо `res.writeHead` напишите `res.status(200).json(...)`

Comment: не могу,  res.writeHead мне необходим

Comment: ага, подумал, что это метод экспресса. Тогда вам надо делать так: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

Comment: Всё-таки непонятно зачем вам writeHead вместо методов экспресса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ result: '1', path: Date.now() }));
});

app.listen(3003, 'localhost', () => console.log('server runing...'));
```

Результат:

```
fetch('/data').then((res) => res.json()).then(console.log)
  Promise {<pending>}
  {result: "1", path: 1622624174762}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь, оказалось, что надо было всего лишь добавить заголовок Content-Length в writeHead.